# Nginx upstream never flagged as down in vts status

Tags: nginx, monitoring, load-balancing

We have 2 physical server which are basically identical (for load balancing and failover)

One physical server consist of a bunch of docker containers including

- 1 x NginX
- 2 x WebSphere 8.5.5.8 instances

so in total a cluster of 4 WebSphere instances as upstream for 2 nginx instances (load balancer and failover)

Everything seem to work (I'm monitoring with "nginx-module-vts").
However when I kill the WebSphere instance I'm running on then the page goes blank and the logs shows

`2016/05/26 14:18:06 [error] 27154#0: *84 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ...`

when I refresh the page then session failover kick in but according to the monitoring nginx is still considering the downed instance up.

Some information about nginx:

- nginx 1.10.0
- module nginx-module-vts
- module pagespeed 1.11.33.2
- module nginx-goodies-nginx-sticky-module-ng 1.2.6
- ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx/ --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --add-module=/tmp/ngx_pagespeed-1.11.33.2-beta --add-module=/tmp/nginx-module-vts --add-module=/tmp/nginx-goodies-nginx-sticky-module-ng-c78b7dd79d0d --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_geoip_module --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid

The relevent configuration parts:

`upstream websphere {
  sticky;
  server 10.0.0.11:9080 weight=5  max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
  server 10.0.0.11:9081 weight=15 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
  server 10.0.0.12:9080 weight=10 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
  server 10.0.0.12:9081 weight=15 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
}
location / {
  proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Host  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header     X-Host            $http_host;
  proxy_set_header     Host              $host;
  proxy_set_header     X-NginX-Proxy     true;
  proxy_set_header     Connection        "";
  proxy_set_header     X-SSL-CERT        $ssl_client_cert;
  proxy_set_header     X-SSL-CERT-CIPHER $ssl_cipher;
  proxy_set_header     X-SSL-CERT-SSNID  $ssl_session_id;
  proxy_http_version   1.1;
  proxy_read_timeout   630s;
  proxy_cache          one;
  proxy_cache_key      key$request_uri$scheme;
  proxy_pass           http://websphere;
  proxy_next_upstream  error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_504;
  ...
}`

Even if I kill all WebSphere servers, nginx-module-vts shows all up.

I must be looking over something or vts is displaying incorrect information?
The problem is I suspect that somehow WebService calls are potentially still going to a node that is down but flagged as up.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot seem to get this to work and I don't want to pay the high fee for nginx plus support. I removed the module nginx-goodies-nginx-sticky-module-ng and patched my nginx installation with https://github.com/kriegsmanj/nginx_upstream_check_module (check_1.9.11+.patch)

This seem to have fixed my problem.
The node is still considered up by nginx-module-vts however but not by nginx_upstream_check_module.

Comment: I am working through similar issues now however I am currently hung up on this

I am trying to use the following 3 modules:

nginx-goodies-nginx-sticky-module-ng
nginx_upstream_check_module
nginx-module-vts

but I can't get the vts directives to work, any ideas?

Comment: I used the following:
upstream websphereqa {
  ip_hash;
  ....
}